# Crash in Swift struct definition. Have workaround but would like to improve understanding

Tags: swift, struct, static

I had the follow struct definition that would get a run-time crash in Release builds but not Debug builds. An uninitialised variable or perhaps a difference in initialise order?

```
struct Location:Codable {

    struct Commute {

        static let Times = [
            ["seconds" : 30],
            ["seconds" : 45],
            ["seconds" : 60],
            ["seconds" : 90]
        ]

        static let count = Commute.Times.count

        /* 
            next code line crashes on initialisation
            XCode: specialized _ArrayBuffer._checkInoutAndNativeTypeCheckedBounds(_:wasNativeTypeChecked:) [inlined]
        */
        static let Default = Commute.Times[Commute.Times.endIndex]

        ...
       }
}
```

This looks like my use of `Commute.Times.endIndex` is used a little before `Commute.Times` is initialized so that `endIndex` is referenceless.

I can workaround this by replacing the 'offending' line with:

```
 static let Default = Commute.Times[Commute.count - 1]
```

Have I used `static` correctly and defined the struct correctly? It's my understanding in this area I want to clarify.

A bonus:
Is there a cleaner way to set `Default` to the last item of `Times` than specifying `count - 1`?

Comment: As for your _"bonus"_ question: you can simply use `static let default = Commute.times.last!`. You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names (hence `times` and `default`).

Comment: thanks @DávidPásztor as `times` is a static and immutable I capitalised it. I realise (now) that's not convention and will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should crash in either debugging or release mode.

endIndex definition-

> The array’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater
>   than the last valid subscript argument.

You should get an "Index out of range" error while debugging

Comment: perhaps a quirk of Xcode. If it had crashed on both I'd have reached the same conclusion as you. But you are right endIndex is one too many.

Comment: This is not a quirk of Xcode; its C++ iterator convention.  The endIndex is the position at which you would insert a new element and also the index that you stop your loops on.  I agree its weird, but it has at least 20 years of precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Array has a [`last`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689973-last) member, which is optional (because you can have an empty array).  If you know it is in fact non-empty you can force unwrap it:

```
static var Default: [String: Int] = { Commute.Times.last! }()
```

Although honestly I feel like its weird that you have an array of one element dictionaries.  Perhaps [NSOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset) or an array of tuples `[(String, Int)]` is more appropriate here depending on your actual use case.

Comment: I simplified the structure to focus on the issue at hand :)